# Windows Movie Maker gone and MPEG-2 Encoder is missing

Tags: dvd, windows-movie-maker, video-encoding

I am using Windows 7. I was trying to open DVD maker yesterday and apparently it wouldn't open up and popped up a message below:

[image: pop up message]

Once this wouldn't open up, I started to look for Windows Movie Maker and it was gone too. I 100% sure it was there a couple months ago but now it's gone for some reasons. I don't know if it was the constant updates I'm doing (e.g. the Service Pack 1).

How do I get Windows Movie Maker and DVD Maker back? I've tried to download Windows Movie Maker but it would not install, said "internet connection isn't reached" or something. My internet connection is fast and running perfect, don't know why it says that.

This morning, I downloaded an encoder pack and it was a virus, got me so mad! After I installed it, my computer started to run any programe that I start, say if I open up Firefox, it will keep opening Firefox like forever and never stop so it froze up my laptop.

---

*Update:* I cleared my computer of the virus, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Well you've got yourself in a bit of a situation here. You should first read: [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware) and try to get rid of the virus. After all it sounds like you want to reinstall your system though.

Comment: Yes i know what to do if my computer infected by virus. now everything is cleared and back to normal but still the same problem with encoder and window movie maker still not there and can't install it. Any idea how i can do it? thanks

Comment: I'm not that experienced with Windows, so in order for others to be able to help you, you should maybe include the full error message you get when trying to install Movie Maker.